# user defined minor tics in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a simple way to set user defined minor tics in gnuplot, analogous to

```
set ytics add (gprintf("$%g$", -1.0e0) mytic(-1.0e0))
```

for major tics? mytic in this example is a user defined function which describes the scaling on the y-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading your question properly, you should be able to do something like this...

```
set ytics add ("Label" <pos> 1)  #The trailing 1 makes it a minor tic...
```

In my test however (using the X11 terminal), "Label" seemed to be ignored. -- maybe because it is a ytic...
Here's my test...

```
set ytics add ( "Label" pi/4. 1)  #creates a minor ytic at ~.785
plot sin(x)
```

**Edit**
You could add a label to the above with `set label "label" at graph 0,first pi/4.` if you wanted one.  If you really want to save yourself some typing, you could probably work up something using `eval`, `sprintf` and a function ...  Something like:

```
add_tic(what,where)=sprintf("set label \"%s\" at graph 0,first %f;set ytics add ('' %f 1)",what,where,where)
eval(add_tic("Hello World",pi/4))
eval(add_tic("Tux is cool",.55))
plot sin(x)
```

And then from there you can play around with the justification and offset of the label to place it where you want.

Comment: I have the same behaviour (no label), with a different term but I believe that it is like this because its a minor tic. Your Edit is very usefull for me. I didn't know the eval command before.

Comment: Glad you found it useful.  Good luck.